How to split a PDF into multiple ones, each consists an odd and odd+1 pages from the origin?
From an original PDF, I want to split page 1 and 2 into a PDF, page 3 and 4 into a PDF, and so on. Here is my try on PowerShell:
$i=1; while ($i -lt 152) {$j=$i+1; cpdf origin.pdf $i,$j -o "$i.pdf" ; $i=$i+2} 

This gives this error on each loop:
Bad page specification $i,$j. Raw error was Cpdfpagespec.PageSpecBadSyntax. Last page was 152

I google this error but find no result.
Running cpdf origin.pdf 1,2 -o out.pdf works fine.

You need to enclosed $i,$j in double quote as well:
$i=1; while ($i -lt 152) {$j=$i+1; cpdf origin.pdf "$i,$j" -o "$i-$j.pdf"; $i=$i+2} 

about Quoting Rules - PowerShell | Microsoft Learn
